# Ruby: How to access each element of an array inside a hash where hash key is the array I want to access

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
Array1 = [x, y, z]
Array2 = [m, n]
a = b

hash1 = {Array1 => val1,
         Array2 => val2,
         a => c
        }
```

How to iterate inside each element of Array1, Array2 inside the hash1?

```
hash1.each do |t|
  t[0] #gives me Array1 as a string. I need [x,y,z]

end
```

Comment: from where `c` come ? what is `a=b`?

Comment: Please answer Arup's question by editing your question, rather than trying to explain in a comment.

Comment: From a style perspective, variables in Ruby should be `lower_case` only. Classes are `MixedCase`, and constants are `ALL_CAPS`. Declaring variables as if they were classes is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
hash1.keys.each do |k|
  if k.is_a?(Array)
    k.each do |v|
      .. Do something here ..
    end
  end
end
```

Just replace the `Do something here` with the code you want, and `v` will be the value in the array

Answer (score 1):

It don't give you a string. It give you the correct array.

```
{
  [1,2] => 'a'
}.each{|t| puts t[0].class}
# prints array
{
  [1,2] => 'a'
}.each{|t| puts t[0][0]}
# prints 1
```

Note that you are doing each on a hash. You can deconstruct the key-value pair giving two variables to the block, like this:

```
{a:1, b:2}.each { |k,v| p k; p v }
#prints :a
#prints 1
#prints :b
#prints 2
```